# How to use data of one table in 'where' clause of another table?

Tags: php, mysql

i need ur help guys..i m making website for 'home docor ideas'..i have a log in form(login-form.php) in which when 'log in' and 'password' is inserted,after verification through login-execute.php, redirected to viewOrder.php where user can view all of the orders ordered by clients.. all is fine up till here.. but what i want is,when user get logged in ,he view only that order which is ordered by him not all customer's orders.. two tables are there in database: members and order_insert.. in 'members' table, login and password is stored and in 'order_insert',orders of customers is stored.. codes of these three pages is as follows..

.........................

```
login-form.php
```

.........................

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="login-exec.php">
  <table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="112"><b>Login</b></td>
      <td width="188"><input name="login" type="text" class="textfield" id="login" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Password</b></td>
      <td><input name="password" type="password" class="textfield" id="password" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

.........................
login-execute.php
.........................

```
<?php
    //Start session
    session_start();

    //Include database connection details
    require_once('config.php');

    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;

    //Connect to mysql server
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");
    }

    //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
    function clean($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }

    //Sanitize the POST values
    $login = clean($_POST['login']);
    $password = clean($_POST['password']);

    //Input Validations
    if($login == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Login ID missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }
    if($password == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }

    //If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
    if($errflag) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        session_write_close();
        header("location: login-form.php");
        exit();
    }

    //Create query
    $qry="SELECT * FROM members WHERE login='$login' AND passwd='".md5($_POST['password'])."'";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);

    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            //Login Successful
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['member_id'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['firstname'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['lastname'];
            session_write_close();
            header("location: viewOrder.php");
            exit();
        }else {
            //Login failed
            header("location: login-failed.php");
            exit();
        }
    }else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
?>
```

.............................
viewOrder.php
..............................

```
<html>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" >


<?

     $host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="mydatabase"; // Database name
$tbl_name="order_insert"; // Table name
$tbl_name2="members";
// connect to server and databases
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");




$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ");

print "<center>";
  $output .= "<table  width=1100 border=1 bordercolor=black>";
 $output .= "<tr align=center><td>ID</td><td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td><td>E Mail</td><td> City </td><td> Country </td><td> Phone</td><td>Decoration Type</td><td>Service Description</td><td>Budget</td><td>Update</td><td>Delete</td></tr>";
  $output .= "<th></th><th></th>";
  $output .= "</tr>\n\n";



  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $output .= "<tr>\n";

    foreach ($row as $col=>$val){
      $output .= " <td>$val</td>\n";
    } // end foreach

    $keyVal = $row["id"];


$output .=  "<td><a href='update.php?ID=$row[orderId]' >Update </a></td>";
 $output .=  "<td><a href='delete.php?ID=$row[orderId]' >Delete </a></td>";

   $output .= "</tr>\n\n";

  }// end while


  $output .= "</table></center>";
   print "$output";


?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
<br> 
<center><table > <tr><td>
<form action="home.php"><font color="#FF0000"><input type="submit" name="btn" style="color:#CC0000" value="<--Back" ></font></form></td></tr></table></center>
</body>
</html>
```

.....
your help and suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to have foreign key (login) in your order_insert table. That means, every order knows, whom it belongs (since login of user who made order is stored here).

Then update your query :

```
$qry="SELECT * FROM orders,members WHERE 
orders.login = members.login AND 
members.login='$login' AND 
members.passwd='".md5($_POST['password'])."'";
```

Comment: thanx 4 reply... i tried it but it is giving me blank table :(

Comment: yup my foreign key is orderId in order table

Comment: no no that's primary key. You need to have member_id in orders table.

Comment: OK i have made 'member_id', a foreign key(primary key of 'members' table) in 'order_insert' table, and have following query: 

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM order_insert,members WHERE order_insert.member_id = members.member_id AND members.member_id='$login' AND members.passwd='".md5($_POST['password'])."'");

now its giving me following warning and empty table.....
 
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP-Login\viewOrder.php on line 44

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc() is taking $result as argument

Comment: can you try that query in some query browser? We can find out, whether there is problem with MySQL query or PHP code.

You can try phpMyAdmin or MySQL Query Browser or some in-IDE build tool. Type it with rough data and we'll see, so :

"select * from order_insert,members where order_insert.member_id = members.memeber_id and members.memeber_id = 'john' and memebers.passwrd = md5('somepassword')";

Keep in mind, that member_id looks like some numeric format. Maybe better name for that foreign key will be "member_login" or just "login"

Comment: i,ve tried the query in phpmyadmin,it is giving following error:
Unknown column 'order_insert.member_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: if it is int, query will be little more complicated :

select * from order_insert,members where order_insert.memeber_id = (Select memeber_id from memebers where login = 'John') and memebers.passwrd = md5('somepassword');

Comment: it is giving the same error:
Unknown column 'order_insert.member_id' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0):

You've put the member_id into your session in login-execute.php, so therefore it should be available for subsequent scripts.

You can read your session data and use the value in viewOrder.php:

```
$memberid = (int) $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE member_id = $memberid");

// always check for error
if ($result === false) {
    throw new Exception(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: You should always check for error conditions.  I'll add an example above.

Answer (score 0):

on viewOrder.php,

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE user_id = '{$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']}' ");
```

Comment: THANX for reply..i tried it, but its giving me following warning:

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP-Login\viewOrder.php on line 44

... giving me table structure only not data in it

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM order_insert,members WHERE order_insert.member_id = members.member_id AND members.member_id=(select member_id from members where login = '$login');

Try the above query in any query browser. Replace the $login variable with any login name and check whether it works. Also try not use select * instead be specific about the fields you want the query to return.

Comment: bundle of thanks.. query is working well in query browser.but in php it is not working and giving me blank table.. posting data from login-form.php is creating problem.... keep in mind that when customer submits login-form.php, redirects to login-execute.php and then to viewOrder form.......i've just updated query and added $login=$_POST['login']; in above mentioned viewOrder.php page..
plz tell me where i m wrong

Comment: Try this statement in php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM order_insert,members WHERE order_insert.member_id = members.member_id AND members.member_id=(select member_id from members where login ='".$_POST['login']."')");

Try the above statement and let me know whether it works

Comment: hi Vinayak.. i've tried it, but again its giving me blank table

Comment: Try this statement in php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM order_insert,members WHERE order_insert.member_id = members.member_id AND members.login ='".$_POST['login']."'");

try the above statement and instead of using select * please use specific column headings

Comment: yes m not using * ,instead i m using following query but i dnt know why its giving me table structure only n not data in it...while its working well in phpmyadmin query browser..

$result = mysql_query("SELECT order_insert.orderId,order_insert.firstName,order_insert.lastName,order_insert.eMial, order_insert.city, order_insert.country, order_insert.phone, order_insert.summary, order_insert.cost FROM order_insert,members WHERE order_insert.member_id = members.member_id AND members.login ='".$_POST['login']."'");

Comment: in the $_post['login'] replace single quotes with double quotes and try.

Comment: i've added these two lines in viewOrder.php:
session_start();$login1=$_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN'];...n query is:$result=mysql_query("SELECT order_insert.orderId,order_insert.firstName FROM order_insert,members WHERE order_insert.member_id = members.member_id AND members.member_id=(select member_id from members where login = '$login1')"); and added this line in execute.php before redirecting to viewOrder.php:
$_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN']=$member['login'];...n now its giving me right result but with warning:session_start()[function.session-start]:Can't send session cache limiter-headers already sent.why??

Comment: hey Vinayak i found the reason of warning.. there was html code (like <html><body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">) before <? session_start() ?>...
now i m getting exactly the same result that i want..
great thanks for your help : )

Answer (score 0):

add session_start(); at the top of the page in viewing orders.

Something like this from a previous post.

`session_start();`

`$memberid = (int) $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE member_id = $memberid");`

`// always check for error
if ($result === false) {
    throw new Exception(mysql_error());
}`

If it doesn't work, try doing echo $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']: and see if that outputs anything.

Comment: thanx for ur response Gus... my problm z already been solved : )